# "Novelty" maximal subgroups in $S_n$

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, finite-groups

What are the maximal subgroups $M < S_n$ such that $M \cap A_n$ is not maximal in $A_n$?

Maximal subgroups of $S_n$ are described by the O'Nan-Scott theorem and very extensively studied in many papers. So I am pretty sure this is known, what I am interested in is a list of examples and a reference.

Is there a general explanation for where these types of maximal subgroups come from?

Comment: The tables in the Journal Algebra paper on the maximal subgroups of $A_n$ and $S_n$ by Liebeck, Praeger and Saxl has lists of subgroups that are exceptionally not maximal in $A_n$ or $S_n$, and the novelty subgroups must be included in those lists, but I just looked at them, and it does not seem straightforward to figure out which table entries correspond to novelties.

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment about all examples being on the lists in the LPS paper was wrong. There are examples in which $M$ is primitive  but $M \cap A_n$ is imprimitive, and they will not appear on the lists.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Thanks, this helps. So seems with the results of the LPS paper from 1987, remains to look at $M$ almost simple primitive such that $M \cap A_n$ is imprimitive. In which case $M \cap A_n \leq S_{n/2} \wr S_2$.

Comment: Yes that's right. I am busy at present but I will try and write a partial answer in a day or two.

Comment: "novelty" is a noun. Why not "novel", which is also an adjective? It sounds absurd and ugly to use the substantive of an adjective as an adjective.

Comment: @YCor: Maybe there could be a better name, but it is a term used in the literature.. I think it might go back to Rob Wilson, "Maximal Subgroups of Automorphism Groups of Simple Groups", 1985. A maximal subgroup of this type is called "novel" or a "novelty"

Comment: @spin Ah, this sounds consistent: "a novelty" or a "novel" (maximal) subgroup. (But novelty is certainly not an adverb.)

Comment: I  has thought that this usage originated with John Conway, but it might have been Wilson. Originally it was used as a noun - this subgroup is a novelty. But this was very soon extended to "novelty subgroup", which is more commonly used than the more grammatical "novel subgroup". I have to admit that I regularly use "novelty subgroup" myself.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Actually to be clear I am not 100% sure, it's just the earliest reference I know.

Comment: It's a "noun adjunct" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct), like "surface" in "surface group". It's the same in "novelty gift". But I agree "novel" is semantically better, unless the maximal subgroup is somehow amusing.

Comment: @SeanEberhard Thanks for the elucidation. It doesn't mean amusing (although Conway might have found them entertaining), it means new, in the sense that the intersection with $A_n$ is not a maximal subgroup of $A_n$.

Answer (score 9):

The best reference for this topic seems to be [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869387902237):

A classification of the maximal subgroups of the finite alternating and symmetric groups,
Martin W Liebeck, Cheryl E Praeger, Jan Saxl,
Journal of Algebra
Volume 111, Issue 2, December 1987, Pages 365-383,

which I'll denote by LPS. Unfortunately this does not provide a complete answer to the question, and I am not aware of any more recent papers that provide more information.

The main theorem of LPS divides the maximal subgroups of $A_n$ and $S_n$ into six categories (a)-(f). (a) and (b) consist respectively of intransitive and inprimitive subgroups, (c)-(e) are respectively primitive groups of affine, diagonal and wreath (also known as product) types, and (f) the almost simple primitive groups.

The Tables I-VI of LPS list groups $G$ of these types that are exceptionally not maximal in $A_n$ or $S_n$. The five groups in Table 1, with  $n=8,7,11,17,23$ are the only examples in which $G$ has one of the types (a)-(e). In fact one is of Type (b), and the other 4 of Type (c). These all correspond to novelty maximals of $S_n$ (i.e the groups are maximal in $S_n$, but their intersections with $A_n$ are non-maximal).

The remaining tables contain the non-maximal examples $G$ of type (f), almost simple. Unfortunately the tables do not indicate which of them correspond to novelty maximals of $S_n$. Presumably it did not occur to the authors to attempt to provide this information, which I expect they could have done. Most of them do not. I calculated that in Table II (non-maximal groups $G$ contained in a larger subgroup of type (a)-(e)), only the first group $L_2(7).2$ of degree $8$ is a novelty maximal. I haven't tried to decide this for the groups in Tables III-VI.

Another infinite family of novelty maximals of $S_n$ is mentioned in Remark 2 of the paper. These are the wreath type groups $S_m \wr S_2$ with $m \equiv 2 \bmod 4$ and $n=m^2$. In these examples, $G \cap A_n$ is imprimitive, so it is contained in a maximal imprimitive example of Type (b).

Unfortunately these tables do not list novelty subgroups in which $G$  primitive almost simple and $G \cap A_n$ is imprimitive, and I am not aware of any attempt to classify such groups. I suspect that there are infinitely many examples, but that's just a guess.

Magma can find the maximal subgroups of $S_n$ for $n \le 1000$, and I used this to find all novelty maximals. (This could be extended to degree 4095 without much effort, using the database of primitive permutation groups.) There are $24$ examples up to degree 1000 of degrees
$$7, 8, 8, 11, 12, 17, 21, 23, 24, 36, 55, 55, 100, 105, 136, 196, 324, 425, 465, 484, 676, 750, 775, 900.$$

Of these, five (degrees $7,8,11,17,23$) are listed in Table I, one (degree $8$) in Table II, three (degrees $12, 24,55$) in Table IV, one (degree 136) in Table VI, seven (degrees $36, 100, 196, 324, 484, 676, 900$) are examples descibed in Remark 2 of LPS, and the remaining seven (degrees $21,55, 105,425, 465, 750,775$) are primitive groups $G$ of Type (f) with $G \cap A_n$ imprimitive.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, this is very helpful.